Does a nonzero section induce Isomorphism of Locally Free Sheaves?
Suppose I have two locally free sheaves $E, F$ of the same rank on a scheme $X$. And suppose that I have a nowhere vanishing section $s \in H^0(E \otimes F)$. That is, for all $x \in X$, we have that $s_x \notin m_x(E \otimes F)_x$.
This section induces a map $s \colon E^\vee \to F$. Since $s$ is nowhere vanishing is the induced map an isomorphism? Or do I have to assume the induced map is surjective?

Do you mean $s_x \notin m_x (E \otimes F)_x$?

Yes thank you I'll edit it.

Suppose $X = \operatorname{Spec} k$ (for any field $k$), and $E = F = k^n$. Then $s$ is just a linear map
$$s: k^n \to k^n.$$
But being a non-zero linear map is not the same as being an isomorphism.

So if we consider the induced map from $det E^\vee \to det F$, and that is nonzero then the map between $E^\vee \to  F$ is an isomorphism?

@SlimShady Yes I think so.
